# How do you POST and receive a cookie in Python?

Tags: python, cookies, authentication, jira

I'm trying to create a python script that logs into JIRA using their REST api. To do this I need to POST a login form (with the username and password) to the JIRA server and store the cookie that is retrieved (preferably as a field in a file).

Here's the login docs:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA042/JIRA+REST+API+(Alpha)+Tutorial#JIRARESTAPIAlphaTutorial-LoggingIn

This is a working curl command to do exactly what I want:

`curl -c cookie_jar -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username" : "admin", "password" : "hunter2"}' http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/latest/session`

How can I replicate this in Python? Preferably without any extra libraries.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use LWPCookieJar

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib
url='http://localhost:8080/rest/auth/latest/session'
post={"username" : "admin", "password" : "hunter2"}
post_data=urllib.urlencode(post)
cookie = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
opener.open(url,post_data)
cookie.save('cookie_filename', True)
```